# In bash, how do I force variable never to be interpreted as a list?

Tags: bash

In my `bash` scripts, I regularly use file paths which may contain spaces:

```
FOO=/path\ with\ spaces/
```

Later, if I want to use `FOO`, I have to wrap it in quotes (`"$FOO"`) or it will be interpreted as a list (`/path`, `with`, `spaces/`). Is there a better way to force a variable never to be interpreted as a list? It is cumbersome to have to constantly quote-wrap.

Comment: There is a better way. use `"` like `FOO="path with spaces"`.

Comment: @Annjawn, you still need to quote when you *use* the variable: `"$FOO"`

Comment: @glennjackman oh yeah... sorry, I guessed I missed that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You must always use quotes or bash will word-split (except in `[[`, but that is a special case).

Comment: See "[Quoting Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)" for more information.

Comment: Another special case: the first argument of the `case` statement

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the internal field separator, IFS, as in:

```
ORIGIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
# do stuff...
IFS="$ORIGIFS"
```

However, this affects all situations where bash looks to do field splitting, which might be more broad than you'd like.